# Cannot set property ' nTf' of undefined DataTables

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables

Hi Im trying to use the dataTables on Altair. but i can seem to work it in my web page properly.

Heres my Html view.

```
<div class="md-card uk-margin-medium-bottom">
    <div class="md-card-content">
        <table datatable dt-options="dtOptions" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs" class="uk-table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Group Name</th>
                        <th>Last Updated</th>
                        <th>Schedule</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

then in my main route I add the "Lazy_datatables"

```
.state("restricted.srdatasource.groups",{
                    url:"/srdatasource/groups",
                    templateUrl:'srdatasource/views/datasourceGroupsView.html',
                    controller: 'datasourceGroupsController',
                    resolve: {
                        deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                            return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                                'lazy_parsleyjs',
                                'lazy_datatables',
                                'srdatasource/controllers/datasourceGroupsController.js',
                                'srdatasource/services/datasourceService.js'
                            ]);
                        }]
                    },                  
                    data: {
                        pageTitle: 'Groups'
                    }
                })
```

then on my controller i add the DTOptionsBuilder and DTColumnDefBuilder

```
$scope.init() = function() {
   $scope.all_groups();
}

$scope.all_groups = function() {

              DatasourceService.get_dsgroup(function(results){
                  console.log(results.data)
                  console.log(this);
                  // $scope.DSGroupData = results.data;
                  var vm = this;
                  vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
                      .fromSource(results.data)
                      .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
                      .withColumnFilter({
                          aoColumns: [
                              {
                                  type: 'text',
                                  bRegex: true,
                                  bSmart: true
                              },
                              {
                                  type: 'number',
                                  bRegex: true,
                                  bSmart: true
                              },
                              {
                                  type: 'number',
                                  bRegex: true,
                                  bSmart: true
                              },
                              {
                                  type: 'text',
                                  bRegex: true,
                                  bSmart: true
                              }
                          ]
                      })
                      .withOption('initComplete', function() {
                          $timeout(function() {
                              $compile($('.dt-uikit .md-input'))($scope);
                          })
                      });
                  vm.dtColumnDefs = [
                      DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).withTitle('Group Name'),
                      DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1).withTitle('Last Updated'),
                      DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(2).withTitle('Schedule'),
                      DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(3).withTitle('Action')

                  ];
              });
          }
```

the results.data is not empty. it has value that comes from database. here's the data.

[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

```
0
:
Object
__v
:
0
_id
:
"578cf46fc80f7ae809a5a095"
lastpull
:
"2016-07-19T06:16:26.000Z"
name
:
"Nike SB"
schedule
:
"01:30"
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
__v
:
0
_id
:
"578d7c1b1ec87f1826b1ca1a"
lastpull
:
"2016-07-19T06:16:45.000Z"
name
:
"DC Team"
schedule
:
"02:30"
__proto__
:
Object
2
:
Object
3
:
Object
4
:
Object
5
:
Object
6
:
Object
7
:
Object
```

if i miss something please tell me ive been bangin' my head for a day of this.

Comment: I don't know this `dataTable` function, and I don't know if this will fix your problem, but the first thing I would do is take the header out of the footer.  :)  (Footer out of the header?  Anyway, change `tfoot` to `thead`.)  You haven't explained what you mean by "not working properly", but I'd bet that the table creation code is going to act strange when it sees a tfoot followed by a tbody.

Comment: thanks bob, you should write the tfoot change as proper reply since this fixed my problem

Comment: I was facing the same issue, then i realized number of columns in thead, tbody and tfooter aren't equal. once i fixed this i got rid of this error.